# Monotouch floating point pointer throws NullReferenceException when not 4-byte aligned

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin.ios, unsafe

I'm facing a problem I just can't understand.

While playing with unsafe pointers in C# with Monotouch, I get a NullReferenceException on device (ARM), but I can't explain why, let's see some code

```
var rand = new Random();
var buffer = new byte[2 * 1024 * 1024];
rand.NextBytes(buffer);

fixed (byte* ptr = buffer) {
    var ptr2 = ptr + 982515;

    //This works
    var bfr = new byte[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        bfr[i] = ptr2[i];
    var v = BitConverter.ToDouble(bfr, 0);

    //This throws a NullReferenceException on device
    var v2 = *(double*)ptr2;

    Console.WriteLine("v: {0}; v2: {1}", v, v2);
}
```

It only crashes on device.
Anything to do with ARM structured alignment ?

**Edit**

After some research I ended with this:

A floating point value can be read only from a 4-bytes aligned address on ARM

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Test(982512); //Works
    Test(982516); //Works
    Test(982515); //Crash on device only
}

unsafe static void Test(int offset) {
    var rand = new Random();
    var buffer = new byte[2 * 1024 * 1024];
    rand.NextBytes(buffer);

    fixed (byte* ptr = buffer) {
        var ptr2 = ptr + offset;

        //Always works
        var bfr = new byte[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            bfr[i] = ptr2[i];
        var v = BitConverter.ToDouble(bfr, 0);

        //Throws a NullReferenceException on device if offset is not 4-byte aligned
        var v2 = *(double*)ptr2;

        Console.WriteLine("v: {0}; v2: {1}", v, v2);
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to bypass this ?

Comment: You need to post the actual code - that code can't compile (`buffer` is redeclared inside the `fixed` block). I tried the code with `buffer` defined before the `fixed` block and the other `buffer` declaration removed, and it works as expected without any exception.

Comment: Thinking about it, perhaps you have some kind of multithreading issue?

Comment: I edited the code. As mentionned, it doesn't always crashes, but only with some specific data, I'll try to post one soon

Comment: I edited the code again, you can now reproduce the crash.

Comment: The Problem is - obviously that (double*)ptr2 returns null. and then *ptr2 causes the Exception..

Comment: Why would it returns null ? The data is here, since accessing them via ptr2[...] works. As mentionned in my post, I found that on ARM device, dereferencing a struct at a non-4-byte-aligned address cause this Exception to be thrown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On ARM devices, dereferencing a floating-point value (Single, Double) is only possible at a 4-bytes aligned address.

http://www.aleph1.co.uk/chapter-10-arm-structured-alignment-faq

So the solution is something like this:

```
static double ReadDouble(byte* ptr, int offset) {
    var ptr2 = ptr + offset;
    if ((int)ptr2 % 4 == 0)
        return *(double*)ptr2;
    else {
        var bfr = new byte[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            bfr[i] = ptr2[i];
        var v = BitConverter.ToDouble(bfr, 0);
    }
}
```